# popup grow right and up

Tags: css, transform, transition

i am trying to make a smooth transition, when i am opening a popup. 
see codepen.io https://codepen.io/andrelange91/pen/QamNZK

i am using

```
-webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition: width 1s, height 1s;
```

on two different elements, i have an image which should "grow" and a info-popup div element.

i am trying to make them grow smoothly to the right and up. 
but it is jerky (ie, not smooth),

and on my info-popup, it isn't working..

```
.info-popup{
  display:none;
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 1s, height 1s;

  &[data-display="true"]{
    display:block;
    height:400px;
    width:850px;
    background:grey;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:65px;
    left:2%;
  }
}
```

on my "image", it's sort a working.

```
.programImage{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:2;
    width:100%;
    height:90px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 1s, height 1s;
    img{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }
    &[data-playerinfo-expanded="true"]{
      height:150px;
      width:360px;

    }
  }
```

I have searched google for a lot of different solutions, but none seems to fit. 
i also tried using Scale, but that created alot of new problems.

Performance wise, would it be better to use transform ?
and how would that look ?

***in an ideal world, both the programImage (image) and info-popup, would grow at the same rate, so it almost looks like the big "info-popup" is pulling on the smaller element "image"***

Comment: For your popup, you cannot animate between `display: none` and `display: [anything-but-none]`.

Comment: @kLabz is it not possible to make any animations on it, to get the desired effect ?

Comment: Not on `display` directly, no. You need to either hide it by another mean, or `display: block` for at least a frame before transitioning to the "open" state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do some adaptation on my fork codepen of yours, this is not clean but you can get what to do.

I removed the animation that you done with JS, and set the transition for popup and image.
Also you could not make any transition if you go from `display:none;` to `display: block`;.

You have to use different tricks, for example :

```
with: 0px;
height: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition: height 1s, width 1s, opacity 0s 1s;
```

and when you want this to popup :

```
with: 850px;
height: 300px;
opacity: 1;
transition: height 1s, width 1s, opacity 0s;
```

https://codepen.io/Alvan/pen/JMLbqm

Comment: Not exactly what i wanted, but it lead me to the right thing.

Comment: Of course, if have no idea of what you want exactly, i can only show you a way :)

Answer (score 0):

In browser all html rendering and executing javascript is running on `main-thread` so animation performance will degraded (if you are using animation property that running on `main-thread`)

Always use animation property that are running on `compositor-thread` e.g `transform`, `opacity` so animation not will affected by main-thread, result in smooth animation effect.

also `will-change` css property will help for smooth animation.

see which property will running on compositor-thread or on main-thread [css trigger](https://csstriggers.com/)

Test below code on full page,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="anime.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <style>
.demoDiv{
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
 will-change:transform;
 transform: translateY(100vh) translateX(-50vw);
}

button{
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 bottom:1%;
}

@keyframes slide-in-fwd-bl {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100vh) translateX(-50vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform:  translateY(50vh) translateX(50vw);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.slide-in-fwd-bl {
 -webkit-animation: slide-in-fwd-bl 0.8s ease-in-out both;
  animation: slide-in-fwd-bl 0.8s ease-in-out both;
}
 
 </style>
</head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  $(".demoDiv").addClass("slide-in-fwd-bl");
 }); 
});
</script>


<body>

 <div class="demoDiv"></div>
 <button>click me.....!</button>
</body>
</html>
```